# AttributeError: 'Action' object has no attribute 'text1'

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Experienced C programmer, total noob at python.
Using python wx.
In the definition of an object named Action, I declare:

```
    self.text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Name")
```

but when I go to access it in the main module on a callback:

```
    def OnComboSelect(self, e):
        print self.combo.GetValue()
        win = Action(self, "Action")
            win.text2.SetLabel("testing")
```

## win.SetLabel(e, "Action")

I get

```
AttributeError: 'Action' object has no attribute 'text2'
```

(I hasten to add that I have gone through all 24 'Questions that may already have your answer' but found nothing relevant.). 
I have checked and rechecked all spellings.
I have also tried adding this function to the definition of Action:

```
    def SetLabel(self, event, label):
    self.text2.SetLabel("testing")
```

which gets the same error if I call:

```
win.text2.SetLabel("testing")
```

(surprise!). (But there are no complaints about the def defining SetLabel). This is the complete code in case required (it is simple sample code so apart from my little struggle to modify it, it is well sorted.):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# action.py

import wx

class Action(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        super(Action, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(450, 350))


    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Ink Cartridge Type")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, 
            border=15)

        icon = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, bitmap=wx.Bitmap('ink64.png'))
        sizer.Add(icon, pos=(0, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 
            border=5)

        line = wx.StaticLine(panel)
        sizer.Add(line, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 5), 
            flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Name")
        sizer.Add(text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(self.tc1, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND)

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Package")
        sizer.Add(text3, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        sizer.Add(tc2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, 
            border=5)

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Browse...")
        sizer.Add(button1, pos=(3, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Extends")
        sizer.Add(text4, pos=(4, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        combo = wx.ComboBox(panel)
        sizer.Add(combo, pos=(4, 1), span=(1, 3), 
            flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)

        button2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Browse...")
        sizer.Add(button2, pos=(4, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        sb = wx.StaticBox(panel, label="Optional Attributes")

        boxsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sb, wx.VERTICAL)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.CheckBox(panel, label="Public"), 
            flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=5)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.CheckBox(panel, label="Generate Default Constructor"),
            flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.CheckBox(panel, label="Generate Main Method"), 
            flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        sizer.Add(boxsizer, pos=(5, 0), span=(1, 5), 
            flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT , border=10)

        button3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Help')
        sizer.Add(button3, pos=(7, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        button4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Ok")
        sizer.Add(button4, pos=(7, 3))

        # Set event handlers
        button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        button5 = wx.Button(panel, label="Cancel")
        sizer.Add(button5, pos=(7, 4), span=(1, 1),  
            flag=wx.BOTTOM|wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(2)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnButton(self, event):
        self.tc1.GetValue()

    def SetLabel(self, event, label):
        self.text2.SetLabel("testing")
```

Comment: Something to note: unlike many other OO languages, Python has no implicit instance scope in member methods.  If you want to reference attributes of an instance, you have to reference them explicitly from `self` every time unless you rebind them in the method scope first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't create the `text2` attribute until the `InitUI` method. But you're trying to access it before that method is getting called.

Normally, in wx's `InitUI` idiom, you call `self.InitUI()` explicitly from your `__init__` method, as in [this example](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/). You're not doing that.

So, when you do this:

```
win = Action(self, "Action")
win.text2.SetLabel("testing")
```

You've called `win.__init__`, but it hasn't called `InitUI`, and neither has anything else, so the attribute doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make text1 self.text1 as well as every other attribute you want this class to have. As is text1 is just a local variable inside InitUI.

Comment: He's asking about `self.text2`, which is an attribute. This isn't the problem.

Comment: @abarnert The title says `text1`, so it's an understandable mistake.  OP has a persistent problem forgetting `self` anyway, from the look of things.  The `sizer.Add()` call for `text2` is also missing `self` when referencing `text2` in the arguments, for instance.

Comment: @SilasRay: Sure, but that doesn't mean this answer will solve the problem the OP is stuck on. A comment explaining the other problems in his code would be helpful, but not an answer.

Comment: @SilasRay: Also, while it may be _questionable design_ to stash an arbitrary handful of widgets as attributes and leave the rest as local variables you can never access again, it's not actually _broken_ (unless, of course, you _need_ to access them again). In fact, it's idiomatic to stash some widgets and not others in wx, it's just that you want to stash the ones that have a useful value and not the ones that don't, so generally you do the same thing consistently for each type of widget instead of doing it arbitrarily.

Comment: @abarnet While doing what you say is not syntactically invalid, doing what the OP did (assign to `self.text2`, then call `sizer.Add(text2...`) most certainly is, as it will result in a `NameError`.  :)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. There is for sure some cleaning up to do. But first I'm just trying to get it all working! I take your point about stashing some arbitrary variables as attributes and leaving the rest as local - as I mentioned, this is sample code I am using to get going. I promise the final result will be prettier!

Comment: and thanks for pointing out the assign error self.text2, then call sizer.Add(text2...) (I actually spotted that when going over the code before posting. Amazing how much more clever I get when I think others will be looking over what I have done!)

Comment: @user3183042: That's the part of the reason both code reviews and open source software work.

Comment: Yes indeed. Power to the people, in general, and FOSS in particular!

Answer (score -1):

Ooops sorry didn't read very carefully.

You can change win.text2.SetLabel("testing") to win.text2 = "testing"
the way this code is here python thinks text2 is an object inside of Action with its own method called SetLabel. Thats why it cant find it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your supposed explanation of the error but I'm sure it's wrong. As abarnerts answer says, he's just not actually calling the function which creates the attribute before trying to access it...